# Behavior<T> AssociatedObject does not work correctly

Tags: wpf, prism

I have a class implemnting `Behavior<FrameworkElement>` with

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    base.OnAttached();
    AssociatedObject.AllowDrop = true;
    AssociatedObject.DragEnter += AssociatedObject_DragEnter;
    AssociatedObject.DragOver += AssociatedObject_DragOver;
    AssociatedObject.Drop += AssociatedObject_Drop;
}
```

And in the xaml I have

```
<Border Background="Turquoise">
<Grid Height="800" AllowDrop="True">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors1:FrameworkElementDropBehavior></behaviors1:FrameworkElementDropBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
...
</Grid>
</Border>
```

I've defined the `FrameworkElementDropBehavior` in the `Grid` and I expect I can drop the same object on this `Grid` because the `AssociatedObject` should be the whole `Grid`. But what happens is I am only allowed to drop on part of the Grid where there's element defined, such as the blue, white or value part. I do used prism to inject the whole `green Grid`  into the TabControl. Any ideas why I can only drop partly?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `Grid`'s background property, for example, to `Transparent`.

```
<Grid Height="800" AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors1:FrameworkElementDropBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Grid>
```

Doing so, you enable the hit testing on the whole grid area including any empty regions without child controls.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by setting the `FrameworkElementDropBehavior` to the `Border` instead .

```
<Border Background="Turquoise">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors1:FrameworkElementDropBehavior></behaviors1:FrameworkElementDropBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Grid Height="800" AllowDrop="True">
...
</Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: Exactly, because your border has the `Background` property set. Try to remove it, and you'll see that your solution doesn't work again :)